# Eclipse: Java3D library cannot be read or is no valid zip file

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, java-3d, shared-libraries

I have a strange error: I want to use Java3D but Eclipse gives me following error about the library .so file

```
Archive for required library: 'libs/libj3dcore-ogl.so' in project 'MyTest' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file
```

I'm using Ubuntu 14 LTS 64bit so I've downloaded the amd64 version of Java3D 1.5.1:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-java-client-419417.html#java3d-1.5.1-oth-JPR

regards

Comment: You still use an obsolete version of Java3D. Java3D 1.5.1 is the last version Sun Microsystems released before giving it to the community. The latest version is the 1.6.0 pre 11, rather follow these instructions: http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Downloading_and_installing_Java3D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not supposed to import .so files to eclipse as libraries. This is a native file, shared library to be exact. It needs to be linked at runtime using:

```
System.loadLibrary("j3dcore-ogl");
```

You need to find a .jar file, which you should put into eclipse as library instead of the .so file. Then you can either attach this file to your library, or link it during runtime yourself.

Comment: Obsolete version and this thing is useless with Java3D 1.6.0 as it uses JOGL 2 with automated native library loading enabled by default: http://jogamp.org/jogl/doc/userguide/#automatednativelibraryloading